# Android app slows down after adding minSdkVersion

Tags: android, performance, android-manifest

I'm building my first Android game. I integrated Fabric-Crashlytics SDK this morning and my game is considerably slow after that. When I investigated the issue, I realized that the issue is caused by the android:minSdkVersion specification in my application manifest file. When I get rid of the following lines:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
```

from the manifest, the game works as usual. I know, it's not the Crashlytics SDK. I already tried changing both minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion. But, the issue continues.

Comment: The lines which caused the issue: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by specifying support-screens attribute in the manifest file. I followed this - https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/sLi-W3cG7Ks/SmH2kIiPNLcJ